# Notice: Undefined offset in Algorithm.php

Tags: magento-1.9, error, layered-navigation

I experience a strange error which is filling up var/system.log:

> 2016-01-18T17:04:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 22  in /chroot/home/www/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Algorithm.php on line 366
>   2016-01-18T17:04:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 0  in /chroot/home/www/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Algorithm.php on line 368
>   2016-01-18T17:04:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: -1  in /chroot/home/www/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Algorithm.php on line 384
>   2016-01-18T17:04:25+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: -1  in /chroot/home/www/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Algorithm.php on line 395
>   2016-01-18T17:04:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset: 20  in /chroot/home/www/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price/Algorithm.php on line 366

Unfortunately I had no luck debugging it. I could not narrow down the issue nor find any related overwrites.

The site is running on Magento ver. 1.9.2.0 and PHP Version => 5.3.24

Any ideas what could cause the issue?

Comment: Did you try switching back to native default/default theme?

Comment: Good hint actually. I'm gonna try it if there is less traffic on the site. For unknown reason I can't reproduce the issue on DEV. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with stores using Elasticsearch and containing more than 10,000 products.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22792